# There's any party on Seine?

Tags: paris, nightlife

I'm going to Paris this month and last time I saw some young people drinking close to the seine river.

My question is, there's some party on boat in Paris? Where can I find this kind of information?

Comment: The search term you need to use is "party boat". A google search for "Seine party boat" brings up several options.

Comment: Note that drinking close to the Seine (especially around Canal St Martin) is a cheap option (alcohol from supermarkets etc) and generally quite relaxed. The higher prices and different atmosphere of a party boat are likely to mean you'd be mixing with a different set there

Comment: What season did you see this? It might have been the plage season, which would yield up a more conclusive answer.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is yes!
The long answer is here :
http://en.parisinfo.com/discovering-paris/themed-guides/paris-by-night/clubbing/evenings-on-a-barge-in-paris

You have there a list of nightclubs on the Seine river.

Enjoy!